# java spring : how can I separate user roles and authorities?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

My current understanding is that Spring does not differentiate a role from an authority, the only difference being is the `ROLE_` acronym for the role names.

What I wish to implement is roles that have authorities. Aka if I give a user the Role ADMIN, he gets all of the associated privileges ( let's say authorities to access routes on the website to update pages as an example )

My current implementation is as follows : I have a custom Privilege class that has a many to many relation with the Roles class that has a many to many relation with the User's class. When the `public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()` of the UserDetails is called, it iterates over all of the permissions and gets.

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role role : this.roles) {
        for (Privilege pri : role.getPrivileges()) {
            SimpleGrantedAuthority auth = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(pri.getName());
            if (!authorities.contains(auth)) {
                authorities.add(auth);
            }
        }
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

My question : is there a better way of doing this ( native to spring security preferably ) ?

**EDIT** : The roles are in a database in order to allow dynamic insertion of new roles. Currently permissions are too but will probably be removed to be hard coded ( permissions being dynamic does not make much sense in this specific implementation )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I chose this method :

```
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Role role : this.roles) {
        insert_auth(authorities, "ROLE_" + role.getName());
        for (Privilege pri : role.getPrivileges()) {
            insert_auth(authorities, pri.getName());
        }
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

The big advantage it has is that it is called at each endpoint request making it dynamic ( I can add / remove roles and privileges without the user having to logout / login for it to take effect )

This also allows me to scale relatively easily as it can be controlled from an interface and / or by script

Answer (score 2):

You can expose a `RoleHierarchy` bean to create a hierarchy between the roles and authorities.

```java
@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    roleHierarchy.setHierarchy(
            "ROLE_ADMIN > AUTHORITY_READ\n" +
            "ROLE_ADMIN > AUTHORITY_WRITE\n" +
            "ROLE_USER > AUTHORITY_READ");
    return roleHierarchy;
}
```

This example states that if a user has `ROLE_ADMIN` then they also have `AUTHORITY_READ` and `AUTHORITY_WRITE`.
If a user has `ROLE_USER` then they also have `AUTHORITY_READ`.

You can define multiple role hierarchies by using a newline `\n` to separate them.

Comment: Is there a way to make it dynamic ? ( sorry for the late reply )  I wish to place the roles in a database in order to add / remove privileges and also create new roles at runtime with no recompilation

Comment: Then you probably need a custom implementation of RoleHierarchy, extending from that RoleHierarchy for bean visibility in spring framework. The setHierarchy(String) you probably want to implement differently, unless you load the configuration from database as one big multiline text. The constructor will receive some injected DataSource or Repository. Let the custom RoleHierarchy bean listen on your refresh event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to achieve this like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.spring.boot.rocks")
public class ConfigWebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**")
            .permitAll();
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/only/for/admin/**").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
....
....
}
```

Thats how you restrict/allow the access on different endpoints/URIs using spring security. Notice the last line, which restricts the access for all the URLs starting with `/only/for/admin` for all the roles/authorities except Admin. Hope you got the idea. For a full blown example, take a look at [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/config/ConfigWebSecurity.java) and [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/service/AppUserDetailsServiceImpl.java).